# Insert key in Json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

In the case of my json format as below

```
var  names = ['Lee' , 'Cooper'];
```

How can javascript programatically set the json output to below ?

```
{"suggestions": ['Lee', 'Cooper']}
```

I know to modify the value for names[0] from 'Lee' to something else. But I am not sure on how to set key.
This is a pre-requisite for jquery autocomplete where the json format must be in the correct way.

Comment: `{"suggestions": names}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var  names = ['Lee' , 'Cooper'];
{suggestions: names}
```

Comment: Great..dont know it such that simple..love javascript!

Comment: @Fairul: you also have to call `JSON.stringify` to get JSON.

Comment: Yes if you want it as a string, just do `JSON.stringify({suggestions: names})`

Answer (score 0):

```
var  names = ['Lee' , 'Cooper'];
var arr = [];
arr.push({selection:names});
result = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Comment: This is not correct, this will give him `[{"selection":["Lee","Cooper"]}]`

Comment: That is correct but if there are many items to be added as an associative array (other that "selection") then this would work.